Failing to find Android Studio AVDs Kernel Source
I'm trying to build an android kernel module, but i need to compile the linux kernel from google's branch to it works firts... And I've compiled many kernels from different versions and none of them worked.
The problem is like if i built the kernel from this repository: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+refs in the branch android12-5.10.185_r00 it will compile the module to kernel version 5.10.185 but not works on the emulator which have the kernel version: 5.10.185-android12-9-00043-g383607d234da-ab10550364.
It's really strange...
Some idea what to do?
step by step:
Kernel Compilation(.config with default configuration - this takes a long time)
mkdir kernelDriver
cd kernelDriver
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common -b android12-5.10.185_r00
cd common
make ARCH=x86_64 oldconfig
make ARCH=x86_64
cp scripts/module.lds.S scripts/module.lds
cd ..

edit module.lds to fix alignment(line 61):
before
.text : ALIGN(PAGE_SIZE) {

after
.text : ALIGN(4096) {

on your kernelDriver root folder create two files: Makefile and hello.c
Makefile:
obj-m:= hello.o
KERNEL_DIR := ~/kernelDriver/common

EXTRA_CFLAGS=-fno-pic
 
all:
        make ARCH=x86_64 -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) EXTRA_CFLAGS=$(EXTRA_CFLAGS) modules
clean:
        make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) clean

hello.c:
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("cathat");

int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye World\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

after all the environment set you can compile your kernel driver
make ARCH=x86_64

To run this, it should be:
adb push hello.ko /data/local/tmp/
adb shell
su
cd /data/local/tmp
insmod hello.ko

To see the kernel logs, run the command:
dmesg

I'm using a nexus 5 emulator with this android image
API 31
(you need to be root to run the module)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
